# Force HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-7.5

I have a website wrote in ASP.Net MVC4 and deployed to IIS7.5, user first need to sign in before browse the rest of the web, so for example, here's the source look like:

The route:

```
localhost/project/account/logon
localhost/project/apple
localhost/project/banana
```

The logon method:

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult Logon(string returnUrl)
{
    ...
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logon(string user, string pwd, bool remember)
{
    ...
    string url = "/apple";
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

The problem is, after user log on, and we redirect user to other link use `return Redirect('/apple')`, it also uses HTTPS `https://localhost/project/apple` to visit the new link.

How can I prevent the redirect from using HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logon(string user, string pwd, bool remember)
{
    var url = Url.Action("someAction", "someController", null, "http");
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

But don't do that. NEVER transmit a session cookie over an unencrypted channel. Once the user is authenticated and you have emitted him an authentication cookie, everything that this user does on your website should be sent over SSL. I would also recommend you emitting your forms authentication cookies with the `secure` flag (`requireSSL="true"` in your web.config).

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [IIS Url rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to do url redirect from a https address to http address. For example this rules redirects all https traffic to corresponding http endpoint

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^443$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```