# Define Https on asp.net

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-mvc-4, https

How can I change the request to be HTTP instead of HTTPS in asp.net

1. What I'm getting https://localhost/files/P-2019-00001/Scan/Request Flow.png
2. What I won't http://localhost/files/P-2019-00001/Scan/Request Flow.png

My web.config

```
 <add key="WebServerName" value="localhost"/>
 <add key="RedactingDownload" value="\\[WebServerName]\Users\developer1\tiff-editor\Release"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpPost attribute on the post method and HttpGet on get

Already answered here

[Stack HTTP instead of HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052794/force-http-instead-of-https)